# Excel - Create a dynamic exclusion list which skips certain values

Tags: excel, dynamic, unique

I have a large data set, an extract of one column is shown below:

```
1:T8-9&
1:T25&
1:T27
1:T30&
1:T19
1:T19/y6
1:T10
1:T26-H2O
1:T31
1:T23/24
1:T4x2
1:T12
1:T1&
1:T6&
```

I want to recreate this column in a new table using only unique values (i.e. if I've copied one value over, then skip this value in future). To do that I use the formula below:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C2, Sheet4!$B$2:$B$15), 0)), "")}
```

This works fine but I also want to exclude values that contain /, x or -H2O and I cannot work out how to do it.

I have been trying to get this to work with just skipping / values for now. I have tried:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15, MATCH(0, COUNTIFS($C$1:C1, $B$2:$B$15, $B$1:B1, "=*/*"), 0)), "")}
```

This gives me the result:

```
  B               C
1:T8-9&         1:T8-9&
1:T25&          1:T25&
1:T27           1:T27
1:T30&          1:T30&
1:T19           1:T19
1:T19/y6        1:T19/y6
1:T10           1:T19/y6
1:T26-H2O       1:T10
1:T31           1:T26-H2O
1:T23/24        1:T31
1:T4x2          1:T31
1:T12           1:T23/24
1:T1&           1:T4x2
1:T6&           1:T12
```

The result that I am aiming for is:

```
   C
1:T8-9&
1:T25&
1:T27
1:T30&
1:T19
1:T10
1:T31
1:T12
1:T1&
1:T6&
```

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Many thanks, 
Henry

Comment: Maybe do `COUNTIFS()` and add a condition that the `B2:B15` range (I assume that's your list you included) doesn't have those in the cell?

Comment: If it's a one- off job, you can filter the column for those values and then delete those cells.

Comment: BruceWayne:- I have tried that and have added in the result I got from doing it, I think that the exclusion of / etc need to be included at the MATCH() stage but I'm not sure how.

Rob Anthony:- Unfortunately this isn't going to be a one of job and I am hoping to make a template that other data sets can be copied into.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formula in C2, confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15, MATCH(0,IF(MMULT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"/","x","-H2O"},$B$2:$B$15))+0,{1;1;1})=0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$B$2:$B$15)), 0)),"")
```

Note that the number of 1's in the array constant `{1;1;1}`corresponds with the number of criteria in the array constant `{"/","x","-H2O"}`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That has worked perfectly, thanks very much! Now I just need to try and understand how!